# Handle dynamic Subdomains in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I am trying to create custom domain names using .htacess

Here is what i am doing

`http://username.mydomain.com` is accessing `http://mydomain.com/live/agent/index.php?agent_user_name=username` (working fine)

here is .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %1 !^www$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^$ /live/agent/index.php?agent_user_name=%1 [L]
```

But now I want to handle other pages as well

`http://username.mydomain.com/blog` should access 
`http://mydomain.com/live/agent/blog.php?agent_user_name=username`

Please help how to handle this as well in .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this additional rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /live/agent/index.php?agent_user_name=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /live/agent/$1.php?agent_user_name=%1 [L]
```

Comment: Well, it gave server configuration error/internal error

Comment: anuhava - this is actually a general .htaccess. but what if i have to open view_blog.php?agent_user_name=11&blog_id=99

Comment: But where is dynamic subdomain in your new URI `view_blog.php?agent_user_name=11&blog_id=99`?

Comment: Domain is the same http://mydomain.com/live/agent/view_blog.php?agent_user_name=username&blog_id=19  so agent_user_name=username (dynamic domain)

Comment: Can you please open a new question with this requirement since this appears to be a different problem than the current one.